# Setting a value of radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

This question has been asked here before, and answered. But none of the answers seem to help me.

I have a radio button group

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tireInput_front" id="tireInput_front_used" value="used">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tireInput_front" id="tireInput_front_new" value="new">
```

I then use jQuery object to determine the checked radio button. I have tried several solutions, but none seems to do the job. 
I have made sure that he object exist, with the correct value by using console.log

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
if(objects['Front'] == "New") {$("input:radio[name=tireInput_front]").val("new");
if(objects['Front'] == "New") {$('input[name=tireInput_front][value="new"]').prop("checked", true);}
if(objects['Front'] == "New") {$('input:radio[name=tireInput_front][value="new"]').prop("checked", true);}
```

As and more which I cannot recall.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Adding `console.log(objects['Front']);`
shows me that the value is correct.

Comment: Your second and third examples will work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9xywmsvv/ If you have an issue check the console. Also ensure you've include jQuery.js in the page properly, and are running your code in a document.ready event handler.

Comment: It should work yes, but for some reason it doesn't.
Everything is set up correctly, the same script is setting value of checkboxes without problems. I guess the problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

why assign an id and then not use it?

```
if(objects['Front'] == "New") {$('#tireInput_front_new').prop("checked", true);}
```

Comment: Tried that already without success. I am assuming that the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what caused this. But by going over all the possibilites again I got this to work:

```
if(objects['Front'] == "New") {$('input:radio[name=tireInput_front][value="new"]').prop("checked", true);}
```

Thanks Rory McCrossan and DMcCallum83 for your input.